# Ratio of maximum to minimum value

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $y = X  \beta + \epsilon$, where $y \in R^{n}$, $X \in R^{n \times p}$, $\beta \in R^{p}$ and $\epsilon \in R^{n}$. Let $X = USV^\top$ be the SVD of the $X$. Let $u_i$ be the rows of $U$, then what is the upper bound on $$\frac{\max \{|u_i^\top y|: i = 1....n\}}{\min \{|u_i^\top y|: i = 1....n\}} \; \forall i=1,...,n$$ in terms of maximum and minimum singular value?

Comment: What are $u_i$ for $i=1,\dots n$ ? Are they columns of $U$ ? If so they should be of size $p$ and not $n$ right ? Maybe the question would be better defined if $X^T=USV^T$.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I just edited the question.

Comment: What are the $\min$ and $\max$ over ? the indices $i$ ? Then I think you don't want to have this $\forall i$ outside.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!